# Python scriptlines = script.split("\n\n \n") TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

So, I am not very familiar with python, and downloaded a script, however every time I try to run it, I get the error:
scriptlines = script.split("\n\n  \n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' 
Any way this can be fixed?

Comment: My guess is the script was written for `py2` and you're trying to run it using `py3`

Comment: Also, please try to put a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that is probably happening is that the *script* variable
is a *bytes-like* object, like there is *string*, *int*, and other types.
So, to split its lines you should put a separator in the same type as the *script*
which is now a string. To solve it just change

```
 scriptlines = script.split("\n\n \n")
```

to

```
 scriptlines = script.split(b"\n\n \n")
```

as **b"something"** is a *bytes-like* while **"something"** is a string.